# Formatting fwrite output to a external file - Implode Error

Tags: php, sql, fwrite, implode

The code I am working on queries a database through php and then placed the results into an array called CS. This array is then encoded so it can work with javascript. It is then **supposed** to edit the output so there is a newline after every row. The latter is where I have the problem. I get **implode: invalid arguments passed** every time regardless of how I edit the implode function.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "*****";
$username = "****";            --> edited for privacy.
$password = "*******";
$database = "********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

// sql statement for tables and naming array to hold it in
$sql = "SELECT COURSE_ID FROM cs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$CS = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // fill array with results 
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          array_push($CS, $row);
      }
} else {
  echo "0 Results";
}
// encodes php array so it can be used in javascript
$json_array = json_encode($CS);

$conn->close();

// fills Computer_Science.js with the contents of the json_array and adds new lines in between
$json_array_lines = implode($json_array, "/n");     --> this line
$fp = fopen('..\js\DegreePlans\Computer_Science.js', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($json_array_lines, TRUE));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I'm at a loss on how to fix the error. Any help given will be appreciated.

Comment: according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) you have the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: this is on the same page: implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order.

Comment: Ok then I didn't see that.

Comment: `implode()` takes an array not JSON code. you turn the array into json on this line `$json_array = json_encode($CS);`

Comment: so if I moved that down below the implode line, theoretically it should work?

Comment: `json_encode()` converts an array/object into a `string` so `json_array` is a string and shoudl probably be called `$json_string` for clarity.

Comment: _so if I moved that down below the implode line, theoretically it should work_ Or use `$CS` as that is still an array. No guarantees I have not looked that closely at the code

Comment: Actually the newlining process would be better done as part of the _while / fetch_ loop. As `$CS` is an array of arrays

Comment: Actually I think you should have a little rethink: The J in JSON stands for Javascript. If you just put the JSON String in the .js file javascript will see it as a valid javascript object.

Comment: what would be a good way to that? fwrite wouldn't work would it?

Comment: I used CS as the array to use in the implode function but I get multiple array to string conversion errors

Comment: You have `"/n"` the syntax is `\n` and not `/n`.

Comment: Nah, \n doesn't help and I even switched its place with array and it stil gives the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

```
<?php
$servername = "*****";
$username = "****";            --> edited for privacy.
$password = "*******";
$database = "********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

// sql statement for tables and naming array to hold it in
$sql = "SELECT COURSE_ID FROM cs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$CS = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // fill array with results 
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      array_push($CS, $row);
  }
} else {
  echo "0 Results";
}
$conn->close();

//encode the array so it can be used in javascript and use regular expressions to format it.
$json_string = json_encode($CS);

$re = "/.,/";
$subst = "},\r\n";                                        --> right here!
$json_string = preg_replace($re, $subst, $json_string);

$fp = fopen('..\js\DegreePlans\Computer_Science.js', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($json_string, TRUE));
fclose($fp);
?>
```